# Grouped stacked bars in a plot from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following dataframe created in Pandas:

```
                     living     simulation
(Q+A) ARCII         60.247557   39.752443
      CDSSM         49.431875   50.568125
      DUET          75.205311   24.794689
      MATCHPYRAMID  62.426825   37.573175
      MVLSTM        93.288528    6.711472
(Q)   ARCII         51.508421   48.491579
      CDSSM         57.308882   42.691118
      DUET          60.374999   39.625001
      MATCHPYRAMID  55.334333   44.665667
      MVLSTM        85.297333   14.702667
```

I would like to plot a stacked bars grouped by `(Q)` and `(Q+A)`. 
The following instruction gives separated bars:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True, grid=True, xticks=list(), colormap=cmap1, width=0.5, legend=True)
```

[image]

I would like something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
df1 = df.unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).loc[:,'(Q)']
x=[i for i in range(len(df1.index))]


p1 = plt.bar([i - .4 for i in x], df1['living'], width=.4, edgecolor='lightgreen', color='#1f77b4')
p2 = plt.bar([i - .4  for i in x], df1['simulation'], bottom=df1['living'], width=.4, edgecolor='lightgreen', color='#ff7f0e')

df1 = df.unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).loc[:,'(Q+A)']
p3 = plt.bar([i  for i in x], df1['living'], width=.4, edgecolor='k')
p4 = plt.bar([i  for i in x], df1['simulation'], bottom=df1['living'], width=.4, edgecolor='k')

plt.legend((p1,p2,p3,p4),('(Q) Living','(Q) Simulation','(Q+A) Living','(Q+A) Simulation'))

plt.xticks([i - .2 for i in x], df1.index)
plt.gcf().gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.gcf().gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]

IIUC:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(15,8))
ax = ax.flatten()
i=0
for n,g in df.groupby(level=0):
    g.xs(n).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax[i], title=n)
    i+=1
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston for your answer.  Is there a way to have a unique curve? To get something like the figure above?

Comment: Oh... now I see what you are trying o do.  Let me work on this.

Comment: @BelkacemThiziri See update, hopefully, that is closer to what you need.

Comment: could you add, please, a way to make it general, in case I have the words `living, simulation ...` and the labels `(Q), (Q+A)` are variable? In fact, I read different folders of data where the mentioned labels and words are variable. Thanks again.